# Is this union of line segments a connected set?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, connectedness

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is a union of two horizontal line segments $(0,0)-(1,0)$, $(0,1)-(1,1)$ and a union of a countable set of vertical line segments $\{(\frac{1}{n},0)-(\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n+1})|n\in\mathbb{N}^+\}$ (all line segments are closed, with end-points included).

Is $S$ a [connected set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_set)?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: If it wasn't connected, what would be your guess at the connected components of $S$? Are these subsets of $S$ open in the subspace topology?

Comment: The top ends of each vertical segments converge to $(0,1)$ which is in the set. Therefore, it looks to be connected. However, it is not path connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Note that we can write $S$ as a union of sets $T$ and $R$ where 
$$T=\{(x,0): 0\leq x\leq 1\}\cup \left\{\left(\frac{1}{n},y\right):0\leq y\leq 1-\frac{1}{1+n}\right\} \text{ and } R=\{(x,1):0\leq x\leq 1\}$$
and that both $T$ and $R$ are connected. Suppose $S=T\cup R$ were disconnected, say by $U$ and $V$. Since $R$ is connected it must lie in one of these sets, say $U$. Since $U$ is open and contains $(0,1)$, it contains some open ball around $(0,1)$. But $T$ contains $(\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n+1})$ which converge to $(0,1)$, thus $U$ must contain some point of $T$. Since $T$ is connected, it follows that $U$ contains all of $T$. Thus $U$ contains $S$, so $U$ and $V$ do not disconnect $S$. Thus $S$ is connected.

Comment: Why is $R$ contained in $S$? It looks to me like you mean to say $R=\{(x,1):0\leq x\leq 1\}$.

Comment: @thyde641 Yes, thanks. Careless typo.